# Powershell script in C# for joining windows domain

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, dns

I am using this function below to create powershell script

```
public static void joinDomain()
{
    string path = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Test.ps1";
    if(!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("add-computer –domainname ad.contoso.com -Credential AD\adminuser -restart –force");
        }
    }
}
```

After successfully script creation I run that script using this below code

```
Classes.Functions.joinDomain();

string strCmdText = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Test.ps1";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe ", strCmdText);
```

If i run script from Powershell ISE it prompts for password so the script works.

Even calling it works but i just got blue powershell commandline and then it disseaper it wont ask for password and i dont know why.

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Comment: I suggest you instead follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/hosting/writing-a-windows-powershell-host-application) for invoking PS from C#.

Comment: @Mark No, i tried to but it didnt work for my case. So il wrote function(its not done, but its just for testing purposes now) to create powershell scripts and than to run them. Other scripts work with my solution but this function in powershell should prompt for password in powershell shell but it just dont do that. It just disseapers.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

It was cause by windows restricted policy for unsigned scripts.

Solution here:

https://github.com/eapowertools/ReactivateUsers/wiki/Changing-Execution-Signing-Policy-in-Powershell